# setup.py put top level module in subdirectory

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have a project that looks like this:

```
tool.py
utils/
    tool2.py
    tool3.py
```

I would like to bundle these into a distribution such that I can call `tool` or `tool2` or `tool3` from the command line. But so far I can't figure out how to make setup.py include the scripts under `utils/` without creating a new `utils` python module. Basically I want to do this in setup.cfg without changing my directory layout:

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    tool = tool:main
    tool2 = tool2:main
    tool3 = tool3:main
```

If I flatten my project directory so that all 3 are in the root directory, it works, but there are potentially many utility tools that I don't want spamming up the root directory. But it seems like if I put them under `utils` that setup.py wants to create them as submodules under a `utils` module.

One potential workaround is to just do:

```
[options]
scripts =
    tool.py
    utils/tool2.py
    utils/tool3.py
```

but then you have to always type the `.py` suffix to invoke from the commandline whereas I would prefer to leave it off so it feels more "command-liny".

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Could you  import the submodules in the top level  `__init__.py` file?

Comment: There is no top level `__init__.py` file, only `setup.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around the issue by doing something like:

```
[options]
scripts =
    dist_scripts/tool
    dist_scripts/tool2
    dist_scripts/tool3
```

Where `dist_scripts/tool` was a relative softlink to `tool.py`, etc. Seems to work fine.